# How to change color of Font Awesome stacked icons on hover

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm using two Font Awesome icons:

- `fa-circle-thin`
- `fa-user-plus`

They are stacked on top of one another to give a circle icon look.

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-sm">
 <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-user-plus fa-stack-1x "></i>
</span>
```

When I hover over I want the circle to be filled in black and the `fa-user-plus` to change to white. How can I achieve this?

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ReturnOfTheMac/Lwdaen75/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To achieve the desired effect, add a `fa-circle` icon to the stack that will be transparent on display (`opacity:0.0`) and solid (`opacity:1.0`) on `:hover`.

For example (also on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2hxxuv52/5/):

**HTML**

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-sm">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x "></i>
  <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-user-plus fa-stack-1x "></i>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.fa-stack        .fa { color: black; }
.fa-stack        .fa.fa-circle-thin { color: black; }
.fa-stack        .fa.fa-circle { opacity:0.0; color:black; }

.fa-stack:hover  .fa.fa-user-plus { color: white; }
.fa-stack:hover  .fa.fa-circle-thin { color: black; }
.fa-stack:hover  .fa.fa-circle { opacity:1.0 }
```